# ASP .NET MVC 5 Web API 2 Exception Middleware

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, middleware

My ASP .NET MVC 5 application Web API 2 returns exception response in a default way with JSON body.

For example 404 status looks like this

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44386/api/test/fake'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Test' that matches the name 'fake'."
}
```

And here is how 500 status looks like

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "My test exception",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
  "StackTrace": "...Here is Stack trace..."
}
```

I want to configure/create an **exception middleware** to change JSON body of results described above.

At least I want my 500 status looks like this

```
{
  "ErrorMessage": "My test exception" <-- just exception message
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In an exception middleware you can access the `Response` and write into that whatever you feel right. Just like this: `context.Response.WriteAsync`.

Comment: I found many examples of how to make exception middleware globaly in ASP .NET Core but none for ASP .NET MVC Web Api 2. Сould you give an example?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that information. ASP.NET Core (maiden name: ASP.NET MVC 6) has introduced the concept middleware. Prior ASP.NET versions do **NOT** have such. So in case of WebApi 2 you have error handlers not error middlewares.